# Random Variables and Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Little Help here

### Q-For a laboratory assignment, if the equipment is working, the density function of observed outcome X is f(x) = 2(1-x), 0 < x< 1 otherwise 0

```
1-Find the **cumulative distribution** function F(x) of x.
2-Compute p(  1/4  ≤x ≤ 1/2).
3-Find the mean of the random variable x.
4-Find the standard deviation of the random variable x.
```

I tried with

1. ==> [2X - X^(2)]
2. ==>{2^(1/2) - (1/2)2 } - {2^(1/4) - (1/4)2} = 5/16
   not sure if am right, also I couldn't think for any solutions for the rest ><

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? And what have you tried?

Comment: It may help to note that the density looks like a triangle, so it is not hard to get areas under it. In particular, you don't even need to write an integral down for 1 or 2, because they are just asking you to compute the area of a trapezoid.

Comment: Do you know what the relationship between a CDF and a PDF of a random variable is?

Comment: @Ian: True, though the result of the integral is faster to write by inspection (for me, at least) than determining the area of that trapezoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers to the first two questions are correct.  You can then obtain the mean as follows:

$$
E(X) = \int_{x=0}^1 xf(x)\,dx
$$

and the standard deviation as follows:

$$
E(X^2) = \int_{x=0}^1 x^2f(x)\,dx
$$

and then $\sigma = \sqrt{E(X^2)-[E(x)]^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

1) The cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ is equal to the anti-derivative of the probability density function. Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
F(x) &= 2 \int (1-x)\\
     &= 2\left(x - \frac{x^2}{2}\right) + C\\
     &= 2x - x^2 + C
\end{align}
$$

Where $C$ is some constant. We know that the cumulative distribution function must be equal to 1 when $x>1$ and 0 when $x<0$. Therefore, $C=0$.
Putting this all together gives the following for the cumulative distribution function
$$
F(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    0 & x < 0\\
    2x-x^2 & 0 < x \le 1\\
    1 & x > 1
  \end{array}
\right.
$$